# Powermock keeps throwing errors for ScriptEngineManager

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

Due to the fact that I wanted to use Categories from JUnit on my tests I had to rewrite some mocked tests with PowerMock (powermock on top of EasyMock to mock statics). From RunWith(PowermockRunner.class) to the below;

```
    @Category(ServerTests.class)
@PrepareForTest(EnvironmentConfig.class)
@PowerMockIgnore( {"javax.management.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "org.apache.log4j.*", "org.xml.sax.*",   "javax.xml.*"})
public class JmsHelperTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

}
```

Unfortunately I already suppressed a few error with the PowerMockIgnore, but the last I cannot suppress and I hope you can help.

The error:

> ScriptEngineManager providers.next():
>   javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not a subtype
>   ScriptEngineManager providers.next():
>   javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not a subtype
>   2017-06-09 13:37:24,660 main ERROR No ScriptEngine found for language
>   javascript. Available languages are:  2017-06-09 13:37:24,776 main
>   WARN No script named {} could be found

for reference the loaded packages;

```
import mypackage.EnvironmentConfig;
import mypackage.category.ServerTests;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was focussing on the `jdk.nashorn.*`, however when I add `javax.script.*` to the `@PowerMockIgnore` it solved the errors.